# Redirección 301 subdominio no funciona con https

Tags: .htaccess, redirección, dominio, plesk

Tengo un problema y no sé solucionarlo sin hacer un apaño.

Tengo un subdominio creado y redireccionado con plesk (301) a una carpeta del dominio principal.

```
subdominio.principal.com -> principal.com/carpeta
```

Funciona entrando directamente pero cuando pongo https lo que sucede es que no hace el redireccionamiento y lo que me muestra es la web principal y se puede por la web direcctamente con el subdominio.

```
https://subdominio.principal.com -> https://subdominio.principal.com
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias,

Comment: Me parece que solo tienes que duplicar la redirección. Crea la misma regla pero con https y debería funcionar.

Comment: Plesk no deja crear subdominos con https :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado la respuesta toquetando el htaccess. Espero que le pueda ayudar a alguien.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomino.principal.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://principal.com/directorio$1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

PD: He hecho esto con varios subdominios, repitiendo las reglas, creo que se puede hacer varias reglas con `[OR]` pero tampoco creo que mejore el rendimiento